# Hot do I calculate an effective forward rate?

Tags: interest-rates

I have to find nominal and effective forward interest rate for 3M-9M term, knowing that current interest rates are:

- 3M - 2.05%
- 6M - 2.04%
- 9M - 2.03%
- 12M - 2.02%

For a nominal interest rate I just solve for $r$ the following equation:

$$(1+\frac{2.05\%}{4})(1+\frac{r}{2})=(1+2.03\%\cdot\frac{3}{4})$$

I will have some $r$ (nominal i.r.) but how can I find an *effective* interest rate? Won't it be the same as nominal?

Comment: This is basic financial question and hence is off-topic here, see the [faq].

Comment: You will find how to do it on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate)

Comment: Not everyone coming here is in an expert and an answer to this could be helpful